# Value of optional type 'NSOperationQueue?' not unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-motion

I am working on a Core Motion Swift Tutorial found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O68O7yUK_9c)

However, I get an error:

> Value of optional type 'NSOperationQueue?' not unwrapped; did you mean
>   to use '!' or '?'?

When I insert a '!' as suggested, I get another error:

> Cannot convert value of type'(CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) -> Void'
>   to expected argument type 'CMAccelerometerHandler' (aka 'Optional
>   , Optional) -> ()')

This is the code:

```
     motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(),
        withHandler: { (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in self.outputAccelerationData(accelerometerData.acceleration)
            if (error != nil) {
                print("\(error)")
            }
    })

     motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:
        { (gyroData: CMGyroData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.outputRotationData(gyroData.rotationRate)
            if (error != nil) {
                print("\(error)")
            }
    })
```

I am trying to learn Core Motion, and these errors are confusing me.

How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Core Motion, it's bad Swift code. I suggest that you learn about Swift optional. here is a good source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Now, about your code: *gyroData* is an optional, so instead of putting the *!* in front of the argument in your closure, use this:

```
if let gData = gyroData {
   ...
}
```

so something like this:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(),
    withHandler: { (accelerometerData, error) -> Void in self.outputAccelerationData(accelerometerData.acceleration)
        if let x = accelerometerData {
            // now x is your unwrapped accelerometerData
        }
})
```

Comment: @IC12 I figured, if you want a good tutorial, watch this https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/swift-in-depth or check out his book. I highly recommend it to anyone who know another language well and is new to Swift.

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial looks awesome. I will definitely check it out.